# Twitter widget for tweeting the post

Tags: twitter, wordpress

Where can I find the Twitter widget that TechCurnch uses to show the number of tweets that particular post has got & to give an option to tweet that post with a single click.

Answer (score 2):

Techcrunch is powered by Wordpress so probably uses this plugin;

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-tweetbutton/screenshots/

Hope this helps.